# how to convert two/there column images to text with ( tesseract.js ocr)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ocr, tesseract, tesseract.js

I am working on a react.js project, I have almost done but my problem is if  I want to convert two/three column images to text by Tesseract (OCR) does not convert as I want. because two columns' text is mixed. no separately convert by column. can possibel to solve this problem anyway?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I9lCx.png)

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Tesseract from "tesseract.js";
import ClipboardJS from "clipboard";
import Select from "react-select";


const languageOptions = [
  { value: "afr", label: "Afrikaans" },
  { value: "amh", label: "Amharic" },
  { value: "ara", label: "Arabic" },
  { value: "asm", label: "Assamese" },
  { value: "aze", label: "Azerbaijani" },
  { value: "aze_cyrl", label: "Azerbaijani - Cyrillic" },
  { value: "bel", label: "Belarusian" },
  { value: "ben", label: "Bengali" },
  { value: "bod", label: "Tibetan" },
  { value: "bos", label: "Bosnian" },
  { value: "bul", label: "Bulgarian" },
  { value: "cat", label: "Catalan; Valencian" },
  { value: "ceb", label: "Cebuano" },
  { value: "ces", label: "Czech" },
  { value: "chi_sim", label: "Chinese - Simplified" },
  { value: "chi_tra", label: "Chinese - Traditional" },
  { value: "chr", label: "Cherokee" },
  { value: "cym", label: "Welsh" },
  { value: "dan", label: "Danish" },
  { value: "deu", label: "German" },
  { value: "dzo", label: "Dzongkha" },
  { value: "ell", label: "Greek, Modern (1453-)" },
  { value: "eng", label: "English" },
  { value: "enm", label: "English, Middle (1100-1500)" },
  { value: "epo", label: "Esperanto" },
  { value: "est", label: "Estonian" },
  { value: "eus", label: "Basque" },
  { value: "fas", label: "Persian" },
  { value: "fin", label: "Finnish" },
  { value: "fra", label: "French" },
  { value: "frk", label: "German Fraktur" },
  { value: "frm", label: "French, Middle (ca. 1400-1600)" },
  { value: "gle", label: "Irish" },
  { value: "glg", label: "Galician" },
  { value: "grc", label: "Greek, Ancient (-1453)" },
  { value: "guj", label: "Gujarati" },
  { value: "hat", label: "Haitian; Haitian Creole" },
  { value: "heb", label: "Hebrew" },
  { value: "hin", label: "Hindi" },
  { value: "hrv", label: "Croatian" },
  { value: "hun", label: "Hungarian" },
  { value: "iku", label: "Inuktitut" },
  { value: "ind", label: "Indonesian" },
  { value: "isl", label: "Icelandic" },
  { value: "ita", label: "Italian" },
  { value: "ita_old", label: "Italian - Old" },
  { value: "jav", label: "Javanese" },
  { value: "jpn", label: "Japanese" },
  { value: "kan", label: "Kannada" },
  { value: "kat", label: "Georgian" },
  { value: "kat_old", label: "Georgian - Old" },
  { value: "kaz", label: "Kazakh" },
  { value: "khm", label: "Central Khmer" },
  { value: "kir", label: "Kirghiz; Kyrgyz" },
  { value: "kor", label: "Korean" },
  { value: "kur", label: "Kurdish" },
  { value: "lao", label: "Lao" },
  { value: "lat", label: "Latin" },
  { value: "lav", label: "Latvian" },
  { value: "lit", label: "Lithuanian" },
  { value: "mal", label: "Malayalam" },
  { value: "mar", label: "Marathi" },
  { value: "mkd", label: "Macedonian" },
  { value: "mlt", label: "Maltese" },
  { value: "msa", label: "Malay" },
  { value: "mya", label: "Burmese" },
  { value: "nep", label: "Nepali" },
  { value: "nld", label: "Dutch; Flemish" },
  { value: "nor", label: "Norwegian" },
  { value: "ori", label: "Oriya" },
  { value: "pan", label: "Panjabi; Punjabi" },
  { value: "pol", label: "Polish" },
  { value: "por", label: "Portuguese" },
  { value: "pus", label: "Pushto; Pashto" },
  { value: "ron", label: "Romanian; Moldavian; Moldovan" },
  { value: "rus", label: "Russian" },
  { value: "san", label: "Sanskrit" },
  { value: "sin", label: "Sinhala; Sinhalese" },
  { value: "slk", label: "Slovak" },
  { value: "slv", label: "Slovenian" },
  { value: "spa", label: "Spanish; Castilian" },
  { value: "spa_old", label: "Spanish; Castilian - Old" },
  { value: "sqi", label: "Albanian" },
  { value: "srp", label: "Serbian" },
  { value: "srp_latn", label: "Serbian - Latin" },
  { value: "swa", label: "Swahili" },
  { value: "swe", label: "Swedish" },
  { value: "syr", label: "Syriac" },
  { value: "tam", label: "Tamil" },
  { value: "tel", label: "Telugu" },
  { value: "tgk", label: "Tajik" },
  { value: "tgl", label: "Tagalog" },
  { value: "tha", label: "Thai" },
  { value: "tir", label: "Tigrinya" },
  { value: "tur", label: "Turkish" },
  { value: "uig", label: "Uighur; Uyghur" },
  { value: "ukr", label: "Ukrainian" },
  { value: "urd", label: "Urdu" },
  { value: "uzb", label: "Uzbek" },
  { value: "uzb_cyrl", label: "Uzbek - Cyrillic" },
  { value: "vie", label: "Vietnamese" },
  { value: "yid", label: "Yiddish" }
];


const ImagesToText = () => {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [images, setImages] = useState([]);
  const [texts, setTexts] = useState([]);
  const [progress, setProgress] = useState(0);
  const [currentImageIndex, setCurrentImageIndex] = useState(0);
  const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState("");
  const [errorLanguagesMessage, setErrorLanguagesMessage] = useState("");
  const [selectedLanguages, setSelectedLanguages] = useState([]);



  const handleImageUpload = (e) => {
    const selectedImages = Array.from(e.target.files);
    setImages(selectedImages);
    setErrorMessage("");
  };

  const handleCopyText = () => {
    const textWithSoftLineBreaks = texts.join("\n");
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(textWithSoftLineBreaks);
  };

  const handleDownloadText = () => {
    const element = document.createElement("a");
    const textBlob = new Blob([texts.join("\n")], { type: "text/plain" });
    element.href = URL.createObjectURL(textBlob);
    element.download = "converted_text.txt";
    document.body.appendChild(element);
    element.click();
    document.body.removeChild(element);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const clipboard = new ClipboardJS(".copy-button");

    clipboard.on("success", (e) => {
      e.clearSelection();
    });

    return () => {
      clipboard.destroy();
    };
  }, [texts]);

  const handleReset = () => {
    setIsLoading(false);
    setImages([]);
    setTexts([]);
    setProgress(0);
    setCurrentImageIndex(0);
    setErrorMessage("");
    setErrorLanguagesMessage("");

    window.location.reload();
  };

  const handleSubmit = async () => {
    if (images.length === 0) {
      setErrorMessage("Select an image to convert.");
      return;
    }

    if (selectedLanguages.length === 0) {
      setErrorLanguagesMessage("Select any language.");
      return;
    }

    setIsLoading(true);
    setProgress(0);
    setTexts([]);
    setCurrentImageIndex(0);
    setErrorMessage("");
    setErrorLanguagesMessage("");

    const totalImages = images.length;
    let processedImages = 0;

    if (Array.isArray(images)) {
      for (const [index, image] of images?.entries()) {
        setCurrentImageIndex(index + 1);

        try {
          const result = await Tesseract.recognize(
            image,
            selectedLanguages.map((lang) => lang.value).join("+")
          );
          const paragraphs = result.data.text.split("\n\n");
          const formattedParagraphs = paragraphs.map((paragraph) => {
            const sentences = paragraph.split(/[.|?]\s/);
            return sentences.join(" ");
          });
          setTexts((prevTexts) => [...prevTexts, ...formattedParagraphs]);
        } catch (err) {
          console.error(err);
          // Clear texts and stop conversion process immediately on error
          setTexts([]);
          setProgress(0);
          setIsLoading(false);
          return;
        } finally {
          processedImages++;
          const currentProgress = (processedImages / totalImages) * 100;
          setProgress(currentProgress);
        }
      }
    } else {
      console.error("Images is not an array.");
    }

    setIsLoading(false);
  };

  return (
    <div className="container" style={{ height: "97vh" }}>
      <div className="row h-100 mt-3">
        <div className="col-md-3 left-bar sticky-top border 1 ms-2">
          <h1 className="center py-3 mc-5 underline">Images to text (ocr)</h1>
          <input
            type="file"
            onChange={handleImageUpload}
            className="form-control mt-5 mb-2"
            multiple
            accept="image/*"
          />
          {errorMessage && <p className="text-danger">{errorMessage}</p>}
          <Select
            isMulti
            options={languageOptions}
            value={selectedLanguages}
            onChange={setSelectedLanguages}
            placeholder="Select languages..."
          />

          {errorLanguagesMessage && (
            <p className="text-danger">{errorLanguagesMessage}</p>
          )}

          <input
            type="button"
            onClick={handleSubmit}
            className="btn btn-outline-success mt-3"
            value="Start Convert"
          />
          {texts.length > 0 && (
            <button
              className="btn btn-primary mt-3 ms-1"
              onClick={handleDownloadText}
            >
              Download Text
            </button>
          )}
          <div className="mt-1">
            <button className=" btn ml-2 btn-danger" onClick={handleReset}>
              Reset
            </button>

            <button
              className="mt-3 btn btn-secondary d-inline ms-1 "
              onClick={handleCopyText}
            >
              Copy Text
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="col-md-8 right-bar border 1 ms-2">
          <h4 className="mt-5 text-center">Select an Image to convert (ocr)</h4>
          {isLoading && (
            <div className="text-center">
              <div className="text-center">
                <progress
                  className="custom-progress-bar"
                  value={progress}
                  max="100"
                ></progress>
                <p className="text-center py-0 my-0">
                  Converting...: {progress.toFixed(0)}% ({currentImageIndex} of{" "}
                  {images.length})
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          )}
          {!isLoading && texts.length > 0 && (
            <div>
              <div className="form-control box-p w-100 mt-5 m-none">
                {texts.map((paragraph, index) => (
                  <p key={index}>{paragraph}</p>
                ))}
              </div>
            </div>
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ImagesToText;
```

I tried with opencv.js but I can't solve it.

Answer (score 1):

Try utilizing a different [Page Segmentation Mode (PSM)](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/blob/4.0.0/src/ccstruct/publictypes.h#L163). By default, [TesseractJS utilizes](https://github.com/naptha/tesseract.js/blob/master/docs/api.md#workersetparametersparams-jobid-promise) `PSM_SINGLE_BLOCK`, which assumes that the text is coming as a single uniform block, which is not the case here. I'd recommend trying `PSM_AUTO_OSD` and see what results you get, and experiment further with the other PSMs.

I utilized `PSM_AUTO_OSD` with your document and found that it printed column 1 (left), followed by column 2 (right).

Comment: thx. I will try these methods.